# Is this function locally Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ be a real function defined by $f(u)=-ue^{\alpha u}\ln(\lvert u \rvert)$ if $u \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Let $u_0 \in \mathbb{R}^+$ for the following problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u'(t)=f(u(t)), t\in \mathbb{R}\\ 
u(0)=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I'm trying to see under which conditions $f$ is locally Lipschitz. I tried the mean value theorem without much success.

Comment: The function $f$ is never locally Lipschitz. Indeed, the ration $\frac{f(u) - f(0)}{u}$ is not bounded as $u$ tends to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us compute $f'(u)$ for $u > 0$:
$$ f'(u) = -e^{\alpha u}\log(u)-\alpha u e^{\alpha u}\log(u) - e^{\alpha u} = -e^{\alpha u}(\log(u)+\alpha u \log(u) +1) $$

This is continuous on $(0,+\infty)$, so it is locally bounded on $(0,+\infty)$. Hence, $f$ is locally Lipschitz on $(0,+\infty)$.

However,
$$ \lim_{u \to 0⁺} f'(u) = +\infty, $$
hence $f$ is not locally Lipschity on $\mathbb{R}$.

If your initial condition $u_0$ is strictly positive, there is local (in time) existence and uniqueness to the Cauchy problem.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, there is always local existence for the Cauchy problem (by Peano's theorem), but the solution is \emph{a priori} not unique.

Comment: Ok understood.. So in general when I want to disprove Lipschitz-continuity at a point, I compute the limit of $f'$ at that point?

Comment: If $f$ is not Lipschitz at $x$, it will not be derivable at $x$, so you should compute $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$.